# nnn file manager not allowing me to press r key for batch rename

Tags: bash, nnn

I am using Arch and bash.
All packages are current and up to date.

I am using the `nnn` file manager.

I go into `nnn` and make a selection of 3 files by pressing the space bar while over each of the three files. This is how files are selected in nnn.

Then I should be able to press the `r` key to batch edit the selected filenames in neo-vim.

When I press `r` I see `failed!` in the bottom left hand corner of the terminal.

This is a rapid and very useful way to re-name files in a dir.

It was working and for some unknown reason has stopped.

ps nnn has no `.config` file to speak of and is set-up in `.bashrc`.
Within `.bashrc` I have the following:

```
# setup bookmarks in nnn
export NNN_BMS='s:/home/$USER/linux_config'

# set nnn editor
NNN_USE_EDITOR='/usr/bin/nvim' 

export NNN_OPTS="H"
```

Comment: when I comment out the bookmarks line in `.bashrc` the problem persists

Comment: same `failure!` response to the `r` key when using `termite`, `lxterminal` or `xfceterminal` to launch `nnn` from, in any directory I have tried

Answer (score 1):

This is a working solution

`nnn` has many plugins as we see here https://github.com/jarun/nnn/tree/master/plugins

After reading this https://github.com/jarun/nnn/wiki/Troubleshooting#default-batch-rename-limits on the `nnn` page, I decided to download all the plugins, I will explore some of these anyway, so I could have use of the `.nmv` plugin, thinking it's presence might solve the problem.

So I opened up `/home/$USER/.config/nnn/plugins` and git cloned the plugins from here https://github.com/jarun/nnn.git into the plugins directory, and now everything is working.

The `r` key is now working as it should and I can batch edit file names again.

I'm sure this worked before without the plugins installed, so I still don't know why it did not work without them.

But it's a working solution if anyone else comes across this problem.

Still, I'd be interested to know what the problem is if anyone has any ideas.